# How can I have 2 objects of the same type in my class?

Tags: java, database, oracle, hibernate, object

I have a class that needs to have 2 objects of the same type. I am using Hibernate, which creates my database schema based on my classes.

Attributes:

```
private User user;
private User keyAccountManager;
```

Getter/Setter:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
@ForeignKey(name = "license_users_fk")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "userId")
@ForeignKey(name = "license_kam_fk")
public User getKeyAccountManager() {
    return keyAccountManager;
}
```

If I do it like this, I get this error:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: License column: userId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:670)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkPropertyColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:692)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.checkColumnDuplication(PersistentClass.java:714)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.PersistentClass.validate(PersistentClass.java:468)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.RootClass.validate(RootClass.java:215)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validate(Configuration.java:1135)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1320)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.buildSessionFactory(AnnotationConfiguration.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:669)
    ... 55 more
```

When I change it to `@JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable=false, updatable=false)`, it deploys without problems, the column is created in the database, but when I call setKeyAccountManager(), the value is not set in the database.

How can I have 2 objects of the same type in this class? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that the class that needs to have 2 User type is mapped to a table called `License`

`name` attribute of  `@JoinColumn` defines the name of column in the License table that has the foreign key constraint to the User table . It is definitely not refer to the primary key of the User table as this information should be annotated on the User class itself.

So , in your case , you should define `@JoinColumn` with different names , for example :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "user_Id")
@ForeignKey(name = "license_users_fk")
public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "key_acct_mgr_id")
@ForeignKey(name = "license_kam_fk")
public User getKeyAccountManager() {
    return keyAccountManager;
}
```

Then , it is mapped to the following table structure:

```
==================================================
| License                                        |
==================================================
|id (Primary key of table License)               |
|user_Id (Foreign key to the User Table)         |
|key_acct_mgr_id (Foreign key to the User Table) |
==================================================
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried this, but the table is not updated with "key_acct_mgr_id". Any idea?

Comment: did you try to set the `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` to `update` and let hibernate update the structure for you ? After that , revise your table manually and remove the unnecessary things.

Comment: Yes the property was set. After restarting the computer this morning and after cleaning the DB, it finally works :) Answer accepted, thanks a lot for the support!

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't that they are of the same class.  The problem is that they are both mapping to the column userId.

Hibernate is expecting either getKeyAccountManager() to represent the userId column or getUser() to, not both of them.

Perhaps you're referencing the wrong column?

Comment: The userId is the ID of the user class. What else should I reference?

Comment: The comment section on here is a bit small to explain what the annotations mean, but in short, the JoinColumn is the name of the column in the table of the class that the annotation is in.  I can try to clarify more if you want.

Comment: Yes please! :) Afaik, it is not a String that can be set randomly?

Comment: Will have to wait till tomorrow for a full explanation, but the gist of it is that userId belongs to the class with @JoinColumn(name = "userId") in it, not to the User class.  So basically, when you have two @JoinColumn(name = "userId"), you're telling doctrine that the userId value maps to two different items across different foreign keys.  One column can map to multiple things, but one column cannot have multiple mappings.  Is the keyAccountManager always == the user?  Because that's what your annotations are saying.

Comment: A license always has a reference to the user that created the license. Furthermore, a license can have a reference to the KAM. I think this is a logical problem in my head, but I don't know how it can be solved..

Comment: @corbin - The Comments section is small because it is not meant for explanations.  Instead you should edit your answer to include your elucidations.